# How to set column by two tables from side by side in union SQL query

Tags: sql, union

I want to show two different data from two different table in two side by side column by union SQL query

Let's see an example of it - here is my code:

```
select CashIN_ID, '' as cashout 
from tbl_CashIN 
where CashIN_ID != 0

union 

select '', CashOut 
from tbl_cashout
```

This statement shows the following output:

```
CashIN_ID | cashout
----------+---------
1         |  0 
2         |  0  
3         |  0
0         |  1
0         |  2
0         |  3
```

But I don't want this type of output

I want to hide the 0 or can be said that I don't want to show the null value or 0

I want output like this:

```
CashIN_ID | cashout
----------+--------
1         |  1 
2         |  2  
3         |  3
4         |  null
```

How can get this output from my SQL query or any other query?

Comment: Which dbms returns `0` when you select `''`?!?

Comment: What's the expected result if there are 4 rows from one of the queries, and 3 from the other one?

Comment: As @jarlh mentioned, be more clear in your question. Look out for join instead of union if you want results like you have mentioned.

Comment: And if you change the CashIN_ID 2 to 5? What's the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your sample output just you could use join

```
select t1.CashIN_ID,t2.CashOut
from    
tbl_CashIN t1 
left join tbl_cashout t2     
on t1.CashIN_ID=t2.CashOut
```

Comment: It will need to be an outer join (to allow nulls to come through where there are no matching records), but otherwise this is the way to do it.

Comment: LEFT join tbl_cashout t2, add left on join to add consider null values

Comment: as per I edit question for what I want output at that thing is not done by join query.